# GRUB loader and USB keyboard

Tags: grub2

My wireless USB keyboard is not recognised by GRUB loader, but I use to wait for 10 seconds and Ubuntu was started since it is default in the boot menu.

This morning, no 10 seconds countdown was performed and I was unable to boot, I just stuck in the GRUB menu.

I took PS2 keyboard, connected it and booted.

Any idea how this happened? Some update?

Now I want to configure GRUB to automatically, with no countdown, boot first menu option.

Part of my current /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Comment: You should look for an option concerning legacy usb support in your cmos (bios) settings and activate it. I used to have the same problem and took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, I google that out, thanks. But I want to configure GRUB to pick and run Ubunutu by default, without me touching the keyboard.

Comment: as it shows in your /etc/default/grub the default is 0 (i.e. the first option which i'm guessing is ubuntu) now all you need to change is the grub timeout value to 0 and run a sudo update-grub

Comment: But if now GRUB_TIMEOUT=10, that means it should wait for 10 seconds, and boot first option (Ubuntu). But it doen't, it waits forever. Why?

Comment: try changing it anyway and run sudo update-grub see if it works. if it doesn't I really haven't got a clue....i'll look into it and see if i can find anything...

Comment: I'm afraid I will not be able to see GRUB menu if I put 0, and that means I'm screwed :)

Comment: I turned USB keyboard support in my BIOS and now keyboard works in GRUB.

Comment: My USB keyboard works fine in the BIOS and USB legacy support is enabled there but the keyboard doesn't work in grub. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 8):

OP answered the question in a comment

> I turned USB keyboard support in my BIOS and now keyboard works in GRUB